# Not getting provider data when navigating in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I know flutter provider is scoped. So I declared providers (those will be needed everywhere) top of MaterialApp. In a screen am chaning a provider value and navigating to another screen. In that screen am not getting the data. Need suggestions and guide where I have done the mistake

main.dart

```
runApp(
 MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UserAuthViewModel>(
        create: (context) => sl<UserAuthViewModel>()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProfileViewModel>(
        create: (context) => sl<UserProfileViewModel>()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<BottomNavViewModel>(
        create: (context) => sl<BottomNavViewModel>()),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: "Footsapp",
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: isFirstLaunch == true ? OnBoarding() : SplashView(),
    routes: {
      //onboarding
      SplashView.SCREEN_ID: (context) => SplashView(),

      //bottom nav pages
      BottomNavContainer.SCREEN_ID: (context) => BottomNavContainer(),
    },
  ),
),
);
```

splash screen where getting some info from api call

```
class _SplashViewState extends State<SplashView>
with TokenProvider, AfterLayoutMixin<SplashView> {

final userProfileViewModel = sl<UserProfileViewModel>();
final prefUtil = sl<SharedPrefUtil>();

@override
void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
  bool isLoggedIn = prefUtil.readBool(IS_LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
  bool initialProfileUpdated =
      prefUtil.readBool(INITIAL_PROFILE_UPDATED) ?? false;
  isLoggedIn == true
      ? getProfileInfo()
      : await Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => SocialLoginRegScreen(),
          ),
          (route) => false);
});
}

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
}

void getProfileInfo() async {
  final userProfileResponse = await userProfileViewModel.getUserProfileData();

if (userProfileResponse.success == true) {
  print('In splash: ${userProfileViewModel.userProfile.toString()}');
  //from log
  In splash: {firstName: Ashif, lastName: 123, birthday: 1990-02-03, email: 
  ashif123@gmail.com, preferredFoot: Left, preferredPosition: Midfielder, 
  numberOfTimesPlayedWeekly: 4}

  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
    await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
      context,
      BottomNavContainer.SCREEN_ID,
    );
  });
}
}
```

provider model class

```
class UserProfileViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
 final _profileManageRepo = sl<ProfileManageRepo>();

 Profile userProfile = Profile.initial();

Future<UserDataResponse> getUserProfileData() async {
 final _userDataResponse = await _profileManageRepo.getUserProfileInfo();

if (_userDataResponse.success == true) {
  userProfile = _userDataResponse.profile;
} else {
  setState(ViewState.Error);
  errorMessage = 'Please try again!';
}

 return _userDataResponse;
}
```

Am trying to get the provider data (user profile) from Profile Screen. But it always get initial value.

```
class _UserProfileScreenState extends State<UserProfileScreen> {


@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Consumer<UserProfileViewModel>(
  builder: (context, viewmodel, child) {
    print('In profile: ${viewmodel.userProfile.toString()}');
    //but here 
    In profile: {firstName: , lastName: , birthday: , email: , preferredFoot: 
    Left, preferredPosition: , numberOfTimesPlayedWeekly: 1(default value)}
    return Container(
      child: ProfileCardWidget(
        profile: viewmodel.userProfile,
      ),
    );
  },
 );
 }
}
```

Comment: What does "Not getting data" means?

Comment: It means when data is set I printed the provider value. It printing the data coming from api and set. Like first name, last name. After navigating in Userprofile screen again am printing the value. It printing the initital (default empty string value).

Comment: @RémiRousselet also edited question with print value

Comment: Does BaseViewModel have Mixin Operator like this one?
class BaseViewModel with changeNotifier

Comment: yes.

     ``` class BaseViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  ViewState _state = ViewState.Initial;

  ViewState get state => _state;

  String errorMessage = '';

  void setState(ViewState viewState) {
    _state = viewState;
    notifyListeners();
  }
} ```